# Programmable router

Tags: winapi, hardware, router

I'd like to set up a proxy between my home network and internet.
Currently computers at home connect to a cisco router which is connected to internet.

What I'd like is to set up system so that all internet traffic goes through a proxy  - in my case it is a dedicated extra computer (server).

Are there programmable routers that can run some software within the router or using a connected computer?

This way I could use a program to see what goes out and comes in.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to monitor your network then investigate and learn how to use WireShark. If you want to take the long and much harder route of making a proxy server, use a squid proxy. It runs on a Linux server and you can get a lot of user friendly GUI's. Plus there are hundreds of tutorials.